# What is the difference between 'model.property' vs 'property' for computed property?

Tags: ember.js

Going throught the getting started tutorial for ember js and I am somewhat confused by what the differences are in doing

`function(){}.property('model.isCompleted')`

and

`function(){}.property('isCompleted')`

Specifically, what is the model for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model is just another property, but instead of being a primitive such as a string or a number its an object.

For:

```
model = {
  prop1: 'fi',
  prop2: 'fai',
  prop3: 'fo',
  prop4: 'fu'
}
```

If you do this: `function(){}.property('model.prop3')` your computed property will be updated only when `prop3` changes.

If you do this: `function(){}.property('model')` your computed property will be updated when `model` changes.

And `model` is a property in your controller set by the route you are in.

Comment: Aha that makes sense. Model is just a property of the controller's that does it for me.